# How can I set the Title property of an Excel spreadsheet created with Apache Poi SXSSFWorkbook?

Tags: apache-poi

I have a requirement to set this Title property in our downloadable Excel Spreadsheets for accessibility purposes. I cant seem to find anything in the SXSSFWorkbook API or in the HTTP response properties that allows this title property to be set. Does anyone know how this can be set?

[image]

Here is how we are creating the Excel spreadsheet in our Export Controller:

```
// Create blank workbook
SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook();
    
// Create a blank sheet
SXSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet(form.getSelectedProviderId() + " - " + form.getSelectedConfigYear());
    
// Create row object
SXSSFRow row;
    
// This data needs to be written (Object[])
List<Object[]> xssinfo = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

int rowIndex = 0;
row = spreadsheet.createRow(rowIndex++);
String[] headers = info.isActive() ? PTNT_PNL_ACTIVE_HEADERS : PTNT_PNL_INACTIVE_HEADERS;
xssinfo.add(headers);
for(int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(i);
    cell.setCellValue(headers[i]);
}

/**** ITERATIVE CODE to create rows is here ***/

// Write file to response
writeTo(workbook, "PatientPanel_" + form.getSelectedProviderId() + "_" + form.getSelectedConfigYear() + ".xlsx", response);


// setup the response to write the workbook with the specified filename
private void writeTo(SXSSFWorkbook workbook, String filename, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    try {
    response.reset();
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    workbook.write(bos);
    response.setContentLength(bos.size());
    response.getOutputStream().write(bos.toByteArray(), 0, bos.size());
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
    response.getOutputStream().close();
    workbook.dispose();
     } catch (Exception e) {
    logger.info("Export Code Set - ERROR IN WRITING");
    throw e;
     }
}
```

Comment: try something like `workbook.getXSSFWorkbook().getProperties().getCoreProperties().setTitle("title");`

Answer (score 1):

this worked :

```
workbook.getXSSFWorkbook().getProperties().getCoreProperties().setTitle("title");
```

Solution was suggested by @PJFanning